# Android Get url of hyperlink clicked from TextView' text

Tags: android, url, hyperlink, textview

I have a textview whose text is some html including hyperlinks. I have set the textview property `android:autoLink="web"` so that when user clicks the link, the link open in a browser. Now I want to get url when clicked because URLs I am getting from server, have absolute and relative addresses as well. I want to make it absolute in case url is relative. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

write an if statement on TextView click function to manipulate relative urls to absolute.